# Unable to check if null

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I don't understand why I am unable to check null?  Here is my code,

```
Tag.find({name : 'foo'}).exec(function(tag){

    console.log('tag : ' + tag); // It's a null
    console.log('type : ' + typeof tag); // It's a object

    if(!tag){console.log('true');}
    else {console.log('false');}

});
```

I try a lot of way such as,

```
if(tag == null){console.log('true');}
else {console.log('false');}
```

In every way, I always got else condition though I got null from tag.

Comment: use `_.isNull(tag)`.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, `typeof null === 'object'` has always been the case. It's just one of those gotchas you have to remember. If you want to check for strictly `null`, do a strict equals check: `tag === null`. `tag == null` will return `true` if `tag` is `null` *or* if it is `undefined`.